# How can we handle Exception on an Async webservice call?

Tags: java, asynchronous, error-handling, jax-ws

I cannot figure out how to do this, and all the tutorials around the web seem only to focus on the retrieval of the result in the case where everything works fine. But how am i supposed to improve the following code to fetch the exceptions when they arise?

```
Future<?> fooFuture = webserviceEjbService.getWebServiceEjbPort()
        .fooAsync(new AsyncHandler<FooResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void handleResponse(Response<FooResponse> res) {
            if (res.isDone()) {
        result = res.get().getResponse();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Future`'s [`get()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28%29) method will throw an [`ExecutionException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutionException.html) if the computation throws an `Exception`. That `Exception` is set as the cause of the `ExecutionException`.

This allows the thread that inspects the result of the compuatation, to handle exceptions thrown by that computation.